# Getting my JS and HTML form to work with Ember.js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, ember.js

I'm quite new to JS, and have been practicing JS by interacting with a small HTML form I created. I've successfully got the functionality that I was trying to work. Now, I'm trying to make what I have function with the Ember framework.
So I've created a form that based on an entered location, finds and returns the longitude and latitude (I used Google Geocode); I've also created a dropdown menu that based on the selected option, fills a text field with a specific email address. The code I have:

**First, my JavaScript:**

```
function codeAddress(){
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address  = document.getElementById("address").value;
alert("Address entered: "+address);
geocoder.geocode( {'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
{ 
    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    //alert("Latitude : " + latitude + "   -   " + "Longitude : " + longitude);
    document.getElementById("latitude").value = latitude;
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = longitude;
}
else
{
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
}}); 
}
function setEmail(){
    var county = document.getElementById("counties");
    var selectedOption = county.options[county.selectedIndex];
    var dataValue = selectedOption.getAttribute("data-value");
    var textBox = document.getElementById("email");
    if(dataValue==="1"){
        textBox.value = "first@email.com";
    }
    else if(dataValue==="2"){
        textBox.value = "second@email.com";
    }
    else if (dataValue==="3"){
        textBox.value = "third@email.com";
    }
    else{
        textBox.value = "None Selected";
    }
}
```

**Second, the HTML form:**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="GeoCoder.js"></script>
</head>
<h2>Google Geocoder</h2>
<form name="myform">
    <div>
        Address:
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
        <input type="button" value="Long/Lat" id="firstButton" onclick="codeAddress()">
    </div>
    <div>
        <br>
        Latitude&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Longitude:
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="latitude" readonly>
        <input type="text" id="longitude" readonly>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div
        <br>
        Email:
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="email" readonly=>
    </div>
    <div>
        <br>
        Counties:
        <br>
        <select id="counties" onchange="return setEmail()">
            <option data-value="0" value="Choose One">Choose One</option>
            <option data-value="1" value="Charlotte">Charlotte</option>
            <option data-value="1" value="Collier">Collier</option>
            <option data-value="1" value="Hillsborough">Hillsborough</option>
            <option data-value="1" value="Lee">Lee</option>
            <option data-value="1" value="Manatee">Manatee</option>
            <option data-value="1" value="Pasco">Pasco</option>
            <option data-value="1" value="Pinellas">Pinellas</option>
            <option data-value="1" value="Polk">Polk</option>
            <option data-value="1" value="Sarasota">Sarasota</option>
            <option data-value="3" value="Brevard">Brevard</option>
            <option data-value="2" value="Broward">Broward</option>
            <option data-value="3" value="Indian River">Indian River</option>
            <option data-value="2" value="Martin">Martin</option>
            <option data-value="2" value="Miami-Dade">Miami-Dade</option>
            <option data-value="2" value="Monroe">Monroe</option>
            <option data-value="2" value="Palm Beach">Palm Beach</option>
            <option data-value="3" value="St Lucie">St Lucie</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

I started playing around with Ember and have successfully completed the quick-start guide etc, but I don't really grasp how the html-form needs to change for my project to run. So far, I've put my .js file in the "Controller"-folder, and plan to put my html code into the .hsb file inside the "template"-folder.

My main question is, what do I need to change in my HTML form for it to function within Ember? Any help or suggestions about Ember are apprecited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little bit more work ahead of you, and I'll give you a rough outline.

1. Install `ember-cli` (assuming you have `bower` and `node` already installed). ([Link](http://ember-cli.com/))
2. Create a new ember app, `ember new geoapp`
3. Create a route for your page: `ember generate route demo`
4. Edit the page it created at `app/templates/demo.hbs` and put your HTML in there. Use handlebars variables (`{{ model.counties }}`, `{{ model.email }}`, etc.) in the place where dynamic stuff goes.
5. Put your JavaScript in the route (`app/routes/demo.js`)
6. Your functions `codeAddress` and `setEmail` would be actions in your route.
7. Populate the model hook in your route to return a model with counties, address, email, latitude, longitude, selectedCounty.
8. Include the external javascript in your `app/index.html`. This is where you put your script include for Google maps api

Here's a rough outline of what I think your route would look like:

```
// app/routes/demo.js
import Ember from 'ember';
var google = window.google; // jshint ignore:line

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  // this is what will provide the model to your .hbs file
  model() {
    var prepopulatedCounties = Ember.A();
    prepopulatedCounties.pushObject(Ember.Object.create({ value: "1", display: "Charlotte" }));
    prepopulatedCounties.pushObject(Ember.Object.create({ value: "1", display: "Collier" }));
    prepopulatedCounties.pushObject(Ember.Object.create({ value: "1", display: "Hillsborough" }));
    prepopulatedCounties.pushObject(Ember.Object.create({ value: "1", display: "Lee" }));
    // snip...

    return Ember.Object.create({
      counties       : prepopulatedCounties,
      selectedCounty : undefined,
      address        : undefined,
      email          : undefined,
      latitude       : undefined,
      longitude      : undefined,
    });
  },

  actions: {
    codeAddress() {
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var address  = this.get('currentModel.address');
      alert("Address entered:" + address);

      geocoder.geocode( {'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        { 
          var latitude  = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

          this.set('currentModel.latitude', latitude);
          this.set('currentModel.longitude', longitude);
        }
        else
        {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      }); 
    },

    setEmail() {
      var dataValue = this.get('currentModel.selectedCounty');

      if(dataValue==="1"){
          this.set('currentModel.email', "first@email.com");
      }
      else if(dataValue==="2"){
          this.set('currentModel.email', "second@email.com");
      }
      else if (dataValue==="3"){
          this.set('currentModel.email', "third@email.com");
      }
      else{
          this.set('currentModel.email', "None Selected");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And a rough guess on your template (.hbs):

```
{{!-- find me in app/templates/demo.hbs --}}
<form name="myform">
    <div>
        Address:
        <br>
        {{input type="text" name="address" value=model.address}}
        <button class="button" {{action "codeAddress"}}>Code Address</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <br>
        Latitude&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Longitude:
        <br>
        {{input type="text" value=model.latitude readonly='readonly'}}
        {{input type="text" value=model.longitude readonly='readonly'}}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div> <!-- This was the unclosed div -->
        <br>
        Email:
        <br>
        {{input type="text" value=model.email readonly='readonly'}}
    </div>
    <div>
        <br>
        Counties:
        <br>

        {{!-- in order for this to work you must install emberx-select --}}
        {{!-- ember install emberx-select --}}
        {{#x-select value=model.selectedCounty as |xs|}}
          {{#xs.option value="0"}}Choose One{{/xs.option}}
          {{#each model.counties as |county|}}
            {{#xs.option value=county.value}}{{ county.display }}{{/xs.option}}
          {{/each}}
        {{/x-select}}
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Paul Oliver!! Very kind of you to take time and help me with this. I'm well on my way now :-)

Comment: Got a question for you. When I run it, I'm getting the following error:

`Error: Parse error on line 13:
...el.latitude readonly}}        {{input t
-----------------------^
Expecting 'EQUALS', got 'CLOSE'`

There seems to be a problem with the following line:
`{{input type="text" value=model.latitude readonly}}`

Any chance you could take a quick look, @Paul-Oliver

Comment: Sounds like a problem with how I put `readonly` in there. I think we may need to assign a value to it... try doing `readonly='readonly'` (updated answer above)

Comment: I see. Hmm..when I corrected that, I'm seeing the following error:
`The Broccoli Plugin: [TemplateCompiler] failed with:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Oscar/geoapp/tmp/template_compiler-output_path-iZfDQPL8.tmp/geoapp/templates/demo.js'
    at Error (native)`

Something I missed creating? @Paul-Oliver

Comment: that looks like a fluke compiler error to me... make sure ember isn't running (or node) and remove your `dist` and `tmp` folders completely. Rinse and repeat.  `rm -rf /Users/Oscar/geoapp/tmp && rm -rf /Users/Oscar/goeapp/dist`

Comment: Removed `tmp` and `dist` with the command you provided, made sure they were gone before I re-launched. No errors, but now the page is completely blank (white). I see this when I run `ember serve` :

`routes/demo.js: line 8, col 5, 'counties' is not defined.
routes/demo.js: line 9, col 5, 'counties' is not defined.
routes/demo.js: line 10, col 5, 'counties' is not defined.
routes/demo.js: line 11, col 5, 'counties' is not defined.
routes/demo.js: line 31, col 24, 'google' is not defined.`

I really appreciate you helping me, @Paul-Oliver, I'm learning a lot!

Comment: Saw a typo in the route above (now fixed). Notice how the `counties.pushObject` have all been changed to `prepulatedCounties.pushObject`? The error message is pretty helpful here--it's telling you that the `counties` variable isn't defined...but `prepopulatedCounties` was defined, so use that one.

Comment: Alright! Yeah, I'm seeing that. Makes sense. However, the page is still blank when I try to load it. I'm down to a final visible error in the terminal `routes/demo.js: line 32, col 24, 'google' is not defined.`
Any idea how I deal with that one? I included my `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>` inside `index.html` @Paul-Oliver

Comment: If you can truly see that your browser has downloaded the library (check dev tools, network tab to see if you are downloading it.). If it is downloading, let's make sure your route knows where `google` is... I just put a line in the top of the route that says `var google = window.google;` with a `//jshint ignore:line` to the right to make jshint shut up about the warnings.

Comment: Errors are gone! Build was successful when running `ember serve`. I'm still not seeing anything when loading `http://localhost:4200/demo` though. Not sure what I can have forgotten - went through all your steps carefully. I have installed Node, emberx-select, and Bower; not seeing what I've missed. Anything else you can think of, @Paul-Oliver

Comment: Seeing this `InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character
vendor.js (line 13465)` when I try to load the page with FireBug open, @Paul-Oliver

Comment: Try loading the app in Chrome, with dev tools open and watch the console. If you get an error look at the stack trace by clicking on it to see what the problem may be. Without seeing where the error is I can't really tell what the problem is....sorry.

Comment: LearningJS88--if you're still having troubles, try recreating the app as an Ember Twiddle [https://ember-twiddle.com/](https://ember-twiddle.com/). It will help you better learn Ember, and it will help others help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: LearningJS88--I figured it out. There was an unclosed `<div` tag in the hbs file that was messing with Ember's render. I found the error in Chrome and followed it backwards to the problem. It's the `<div>` right above Email. I made a twiddle to help you see the working version: https://ember-twiddle.com/25d53df4e8129311cf3ce179ac554f5e?openFiles=templates.demo.hbs%2C

Comment: Can't thank you enough, @Paul-Oliver, I was just starting back up again. Hopefully it will work now, I'll comment again in a few min!

Comment: Alright, so this is where I'm at right now. After correcting the unclosed `<div`, I tried loading the page; still nothing. After that I went you your Twiddle and noticed there were several files I was missing (`x-select.js` & `x-option.js` inside the `components` folder, as well as `x-select.hbs`) after adding them all the (assuming they should've been auto-generated when I installed `emberx-select`, maybe I did something wrong?) I was finally able to see the page on my localhost. However, entering an address doesn't return any coordinates to the respective fields, @Paul-Oliver

Comment: And, selecting a county doesn't populate the text field with an email address. Did I miss something else? 
I created a `Twiddle`, and I included my `index.html` file to see that I added the <script> correctly. The twiddle is [link](https://ember-twiddle.com/cd1cee3fd11c0ebb85258a52389d3820?openFiles=index.html%2C), @Paul-Oliver

Comment: I manually added the x-select components, but you should already have them if u ran the ember install emberx-select like the comment in the handlebars file says. I didn't wire up the setEmailAddres action because I was just getting you started. You should read about ember observers and set the email address when the selected county changes. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/object-model/observers/

Comment: Alright, cool. I'll read up on that! And should I have another Q later on, I'll tag you here. For now, a huge thanks for all the help, @Paul-Oliver

Comment: Hey @Paul-Oliver, I apologize if I'm bothering you with yet another question, but I can't seem to get Observers to work correctly. From reading the link you provided I do not fully understand how they work. Would you mind providing me with an example on how I'd use observers to set the email address based on the selection of county from my drop-down?